# a, b = map(int, input().split(' ')) ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, idle

Последовательность чисел a1, a2, …, ai,… называется Фибоначчиевой, если для всех i≥3 верно, что ai=ai–1+ai–2, то есть каждый член последовательности (начиная с третьего) равен сумме двух предыдущих.
Ясно, что задавая различные числа a1 и a2 мы можем получать различные такие последовательности, и любая Фибоначчиева последовательность однозначно задается двумя своими первыми членами.
Будем решать обратную задачу. Вам будет дано число N и два члена последовательности: aN и aN+1. Вам нужно написать программу, которая по их значениям найдет a1 и a2.

Входные данные
Вводятся число N и значения двух членов последователности: aN и aN+1 (1≤N≤30, члены последовательности — целые числа, по модулю не превышающие 100)
Если вы пишите на языке программирования python, то считывание aN и aN+1 элементов должно быть организовано так:
x, y = map(int, input().split())

Выходные данные
Выведите два числа — значения первого и второго членов этой последовательности.

Примеры
входные данные
4
3 5
выходные данные
1 1

Не могу сделать код по заданному образцу строки
Если вы пишите на языке программирования python, то считывание aN и aN+1 элементов должно быть организовано так:

```
x, y = map(int, input().split())
```

написал прогу но выдает ошибку
Вот сам код:

```
n = int(input())
a, b = map(int, input().split(' '))

for i in range(n - 1, 0, -1):
 c = b - a
 b = a
 a = c

print(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ввести кортеж можно так:

```
a, b = (int(x) for x in input().split())
```

Comment: Вообще никакой разницы с `x, y = map(int, input().split())` у этого кода нет, он будет работать точно так же, просто написан в другом стиле.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
a, b = map(int, input().split())
for i in range(2, n + 1):
    c = b - a
    b = a
    a = c
print(a, b)
n = int(input())
```

Comment: последняя строчка кода не нужна. Это просто экран, чтобы программа не закрылась сразу после выполнения.

Answer (score 0):

```py
x1, x2=map (int, input () • split ())
s=abs (x2-x1)
print (s)
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].

Comment: напишите, пожалуйста, подробнее, в чём хитрость использования символа `•` с кодом `e2 80 a2` в приведённом вами обрывке кода.

Comment: Стиль кода тоже подправьте, а то смотреть больно.